# Scala how to reference a method that with an implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

The method have a implicit parameter can not be reference as argument ?
In my code ,i create a method that have a implicit parameter. Some time i just want to transfer it to other method . In this time Scala give me error.  See below:

```
case class ComplicatedSalesTaxData(baseRate: Float,isTaxHoliday: Boolean) 
def calcText(amount: Float,rate : (ComplicatedSalesTaxData) => Float ) : Float = amount * rate(ComplicatedSalesTaxData(0.06F,false))
def rate(implicit cstd:ComplicatedSalesTaxData) = {
if(cstd.isTaxHoliday) 
    cstd.baseRate
else 
    0.01F }

calcText(100F,rate) // will get error : could not find implicit value for parameter cstd: ComplicatedSalesTaxData
```

Comment: where is the `implicit` instance of `ComplicatedSalesTaxData `  ?

Comment: Any place i will declare it, but not here . In here i just want to transfer the 'rate' method to 'calcText' and invoke with a specify 'ComplicatedSalesTaxData' that create in 'calcText'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say that you want to pass the parameter explicitly:

```
calcText(100F,rate(_))
```

Comment: Thanks ,but in this case "rate(_)"  is a anonymous method and not a reference .

Comment: It's actually an anonymous **function**. If you had defined `rate` with explicit parameter, passing `rate` as parameter to `calcText` would not pass a reference to the method `rate` (a method is not an object, it does not have references), but to the `Function1` object defined by this method. So it all comes down to the same thing, basically. The difference here is that when given no parameters, `rate` is assumed to be applied to the implicit in scope, rather than considered as a function.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have posted says that the compiler cannot find an implicit `ComplicatedSalesTaxData` in the current scope. Therefore you have to define one.
Then the call should look like this `calcText(100F,rate(_))` instead of the wildcard `_` you can also pass the value explictely.